# Resize all font-sizes after changing font-family

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, font-size

I have a question about changing all `font-size`s.
I design a responsive web page with the font below:

```
font-family:Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
```

and for making that responsive, did so many media queries on font-style property.

```
#menu li{
    font-size:12px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
#menu li{
    font-size:14px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
#menu li{
    font-size:16px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
#menu li{
    font-size:17px;
}
}
```

I have many of these classes in my website and if i change font-family its so hard to modify all of these classes in all media queries.
I change the font-family:

```
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
```

and the font source is:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

So its the most light of the font that 16px of that unfortunately is larger than 16px of the `Cambria` font.
I have a jQuery solution that can scale the font by 0.9:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('*').each(function({
       $(this).css('fontSize',$(this).css('fontSize').split('px')[0]*0.9);
    })
})
```

but the problem is the code disturbs being responsive on resize events. So does anybody have a pure css solution for that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I would say this might not be an easy thing to do, but you should try using less or sass precompilers and setting all these settings in variables. As is, there is no easy solution to this issue, other than search and replace maybe for all instances, if you want it to work properly.

Comment: Why not base everything in `rem` or `em` rather than pixels.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would be to define the general "basic" font-size in a rule for `html` and/or `body`, and in all other rules use `em`, `rem` or percentage values: `em` will always be relative to its parent element, `rem` will always be relative to the root size (i.e. `html`).

So in these cases you can simply set up different rules in media queries for html, for example `html { font-size: 15px; }` (or 16, 14, 12 or whatever px, basically just as you did it above). If all other font-sizes are in em, rem or percentages, all font-sizes will change depending on and in relation to that one rule.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use relative font sizes, like `em`, so you wouldn't have to change all elements with jQuery. An even better, but less well supported relative unit is `rem`. Then you can easily adjust font sizes for the whole document:

```css
#menu li {
    font-size: 0.688em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #menu li {
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    #menu li {
        font-size: 0.875em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
    #menu li {
        font-size: 0.938em;
    }
}
```

```
document.body.style.fontSize = "90%";
```

[MDN article about length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Units)

Another way would be to create another stylesheet for the bigger font which you can insert or remove when changing the font family:

```css
#menu li {
    font-size:11px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #menu li {
        font-size:12px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    #menu li {
        font-size:14px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
    #menu li {
        font-size:15px;
    }
}
```

Because this is quite complicated, you might want to use [SASS or LESS](http://htmlmag.com/article/an-introduction-to-css-preprocessors-sass-less-stylus), then you can make font sizes variable.

By the way, it's (in my opinion) never a good idea to use such small font sizes!